# pg_dump FATAL: segment too big

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

pg_dump is failing with the error message:
"pg_dump FATAL:  segment too big"

What does that mean?

PostgreSQL 10.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: My pgdump command looks like this: pg_dump -Fd ${dbName} --exclude-schema some_schema  -j 2 -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -f ${backupFolder}

Comment: Ok, immediately following the pg_dump FATAL message is:  pg_dump STATEMENT:  SELECT last_value, is_called FROM airflow.chart_id_seq  .  I think that is the problem, when I try to run that same select statement  ... FATAL:  segment too big
server closed the connection unexpectedly

Comment: select * from the sequence also fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that pg_dump passes the error messages it receives from the queries it is running into the logs.

The following line in the logs (maybe buried deeper if you have busy logs), shows the query that failed.

In this case, we had a corrupted sequence.  Any query on the sequence, whether it was interactive, via a column default, or via pgdump, returned the "segment too big" error, and killed the querying process.

I figured out the new start value for the sequence, dropped the dependencies, and created a new sequence starting where the old one left off and then put the dependencies back.

pg_dump worked fine after that.

It is not clear why or how a sequence could get so corrupted that you would have a session killing error when it was accessed.  We did have a recent database hard-crash though, so it may be related.  (Although that sequence is accessed very rarely and it is unlikely we went down in the middle of incrementing it.)